# RewriteRule htaccess to always remove trailing slash even directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The target is to combine several rules:

- never have a trailing slash in the URI
- internally rewrite to the index.php (domain.tld/somedir/index.php) when calling domain.tld/somedir
- **remove file extensions**, check if  + '.php' exists and eventually internally rewrite to it

This is to be done in '.htaccess' as this is my only accessible .

My attempt so far

```
# check if *.php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L, QSA]

# do not allow trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [L, R=301]
```

The difficulty here is that the query 'domain.tld/somedir' normally calls the directory's index.php after having been redirected to 'domain.tld/somedir/'. However, I would like the index.php to be internally called (no 301) **directly** when querying 'domain.tld/somedir'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: this looks to me being the best solution

Comment: found this after couple of hours. . .this answer is the perfect solution to removing trailing slash and internally forwarding request.

Comment: I used your example but it doesn't work for directory, even it `DirectorySlash off` is set. it returns a 403 error!

Comment: @dcdeiv: Please post a new question with details about your setup so that I can investigate and answer.

Comment: @anubhava here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660361/how-to-remove-php-index-php-and-trailing-slash-from-ulrs-before-ancors-an

Comment: This code does the redirecting of domain.com/whateverdir to domain.com/whateverdir.php (even if dir exists), but doesn't help when you type domain.com/whateverdir/ and the dir is present. Worked it around with `RewriteRule ^mydir/.*$ mydir [L]` but this causes duplicite content on /mydir and /mydir/

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate setting in apache called `DirectorySlash` that can be enabled/disabled. You can read more at [httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) but be sure to read the part about why this is done right below where it says "some good reasons". Also note the security issue.

Comment: As I understand this, the main reason is to avoid directory listing.
So I would like to disable the listing via 'Options -Indexes' and still let the querys pass but redirect them internally to the index page. Is there a combination to avoid using the slash and still displaying the index page?

Comment: There is also the statement: `DirectoryIndex will be evaluated only for directories requested with trailing slash.` Meaning that the index page will not load unless you have a trailing slash. Also, relative links in html will be broken because html will not see the current page as a directory but instead a file.

Comment: THis I have solved using <base ref="/roooot..."> ...
But still concerning your advice about security issues I'd (maybe)prefer using only the file extension hiding. (disabling directory listing is a very important task for me)

Comment: Just remove `mod_autoindex` and directories will not be listed. If there is no specific handler for a path without an index page then a 404 will be issued. The security issue is that the index page will not be called without a trailing slash and `mod_autoindex` would kick in if available.