# How to remove slash on directory in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a folder set up like so:

/blog/blog-post-name/post-content.txt

I have another page in the root of my website which will include post-content.txt by including the name of the directory in a query string like so:

/blog.php?path=blog-post-name

However, to make the url look nicer, I'd like users to be able to access the post by going to a link below:

/blog/blog-post-name

I have created an htaccess file shown below to redirect internally to the url with a query string.

```
RewriteEngine on
# if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and if the directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# take old folder and append to query string
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/post.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is, since this is actually a directory, it wants to add a trailing slash. I could use `DirectorySlash off` but I've read that presents [security concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642696/rewriterule-htaccess-to-always-remove-trailing-slash-even-directory/22642844#22642844). Is there a safer way redirecting a directory to a file or is this just a bad idea in general?

Comment: Rename the folder if you are having problems with directorySlash directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a trailing slash for a directory use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have a problem with the above, you can try these:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /example/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Third Option:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```