# How to remove *.php, index.php, and trailing slash from ulrs, before #ancors, and ?queries in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am unable to find a satisfiable answer to my problem. It's been three days of surfing and finding nothing that actually works.

My site structure is the following:

```
·
|__data
|__controllers
|__helpers
|__partials
|__layouts
|__images
|__javascripts
|__stylesheets
|__public
   |__index.php
   |__subfolder
      |__index.php
      |__other-content.php
```

Since I am allowed to only use the `www` or `html` or `html_public` directory in my server, I want to separate content from all the php and other stuff that users won't ever see nor use.

I created a directory called `/public` and put all content the user will see. But now I want to prettify urls for SEO reasons.

I am trying to remove the php and html extention, to remove index.php and to remove the trailing slash from all links including anchors, queries and directories.

Examples:

`http://www.domain.com/` must be `http://domain.com/`

`http://domain.com/` must be `http://domain.com`

`http://domain.com/public/` must be `http://domain.com`

`http://domain.com/public/index.php` must be `http://domain.com`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/index.php` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/#anchor` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder#ancor`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/?query` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder?query`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/other-content.php` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder/other-content`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/other-content.php#ancor` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder/other-content#ancor`

`http://domain.com/public/subfolder/other-content.php?query` must be `http://domain.com/subfolder/other-content?query`

I actually don't use queries yet so it is not important to make them be in those ways, since I should prettify them...

In my htaccess I managed to redirect www to non-www; make `/public` content as root and hide it from url; remove trailing slash (not in dirs, nor in #ancors); remove index.php

I am trying to force removing the trailing slash from directories but I always get a 403 message, I am also trying to remove the extention but I get a 404 message.

Here is my htaccess:

```
# Options
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes
DirectorySlash off

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# Remove .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

# Error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

**EDIT**

I have tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642696/rewriterule-htaccess-to-always-remove-trailing-slash-even-directory#) but it still give me 403 on directories without trailing slash plus 404 su files without the php extension!

Plus if I type `http://domain.com/public` it will give me 403. If I type `http://domain.com/public/` it will not redirect to root.

```
# Options
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes
DirectorySlash off

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: this site should help you http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561403-htaccess-url-rewrite.aspx

Comment: @ImmortalDude  so is this the answer to all my questions? `Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on RewriteRule  ?` ?

Comment: @dcdeiv As i said "this site should help you" emphasis on the word "help"

Comment: Not having trailing slash at the end of directories is a security risk.

Comment: @anubhava yeah, I read about that. I guess I should force it on all links, strip .php extention and than force the slash to it too even if it's a file

Comment: I've posted an answer below to keep trailing slash internal which would not pose any security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way with `MultiViews` turned off:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectorySlash off    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1##%{HTTPS}s ^(.+)##(?:on(s)|)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+public/(\S*?)/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

# remove trailing slash from all URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Make /public like it was root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/$0 [L]

# internally add trailing / to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

But keep in mind that for a web server `http://domain.com/` is same as `http://domain.com` and web server gets `/` in both cases. It is your browser that adds a `/` after `http://domain.com`.

Clear your browser cache when testing this change.

Comment: Can it be used with what you already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39666774/3348195 ? because by adding just the new lines of code and keeping the `public/` stuff it wont work!

Comment: looks like relative path doesn't work: if in the subfolder `public/test` there's a link `<a href="test">test page</a>` that link to `public/test/test.php`, apache will add `http://domain.com/` before it, thus the url will be always be `http://domain.com/test` even though the test.php page in in the test directory. Plus if I type `http://domain.com/test/test.php` the extension won't be stripped!

Comment: yeah, I guess I should just give up

Comment: Never give up. Use solution given above which will work with probably 95% of your requirements and if anything is still left open a new question. If you keep one problem per question then it becomes very useful question for other folks facing similar problems in future,

Comment: Yeah. i Guess i'm gonna Split in more section this answer! As soon as I have some time I will test your code!

Comment: relative links still doesn't work but it does not matter now. I think that I am going to delete this answer and split it in multiple answer. Plus I have to think for a better way to explain my need! so thank you anyway!

Comment: I have spent lot of time in writing these many rules for you. So to be fair, Rather than deleting due to sone small issues, you should accept this answer and create a new one for just the link issue.

Comment: There's an unwanted space on this line (in www to non-www section): `RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]` Shouldn't have the space after the caret. That will do weird things

Comment: It is not unwanted space.  Caret is start of line symbol in regex and it is used here to make this pattern always match and space is delimiter between pattern and target

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you are asking for here can be done with:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

One of the results of that directive is that when a resource is requested, such as `/whatever` MultiViews will transparently serve `/whatever.php` by scanning the directory for matching resources.

The trailing slash stuff is not actually necessary, for so-called "SEO reasons" or otherwise. See https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html for further detail, and save yourself some time and hassle.

Comment: MultiViews is already enabled. I want to remove the trailing slash for consistency. Plus as stated in that document, Google will handle slash and non slash urls like to separate content. Since I use directories that implies that `http://domain.com/subfolder` and http://domain.com/subfolder/` are seen as two separate urls that links to the same content, thus it will be marked as duplicate. Users don't type the trailing slash so I want to remove it.