# How to remove `/index.php` from all urls, including the last trailing slash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been looking around the web and especially here on stackoverflow for THE answer to this question.

I only use **directories** with an `index.php` file in it. Includables and private stuff are outside the `public_html` (*cpanel*) directory.

By using directories, anchor links and queries will look like:

`http://domain.com/sub/#anchor` or `http://domain.com/sub/?query`

And I just don't like it. People keep telling me that this is irrelevant for SEO but I don't think that this is the case. Firstly because I want **consistency**, secondly, trailing slashes creates **duplicates** thus I need 301 redirects! Consistency and duplicates are indeed a SEO problem!

This is just an example of how my website is structured:

```
/
·--index.php
|
·--/about-us/
|  |
|  ·--index.php
·--/contact-us/
   |
   ·--index.php
```

Users will never know that `about-us` is a directory, and they won't type the last trailing slash anyway. This creates duplicates and HTTP errors.

On the web I've found only non-working examples, and as for what I've understood, I have to *internally* add the trailing slash and `index.php`. This helps to avoid security problems and makes all the thing work!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666414/redirect-subfolder-to-root-and-hide-it-in-the-url), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660361/how-to-remove-php-index-php-and-trailing-slash-from-ulrs-before-ancors-an) I asked something similar. But in that case I had to create the `/public` directory. Now I am managing to change host, and I will be able to use the non public directory to store php files.

Since I don't need the `/public` directory anymore, I copied part of that code and pasted it on a new `.htaccess`.

Here is the `.htaccess`

```
# Options
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DirectorySlash off

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1##%{HTTPS}s ^(.+)##(?:on(s)|)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# remove trailing slash from all URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# internally add trailing / to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

<FilesMatch ^\.>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files *.inc>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

The code seems to work well in subdirectories but not in root. I guess that this is because the code above was tailored to work on the `/public` subdirectory.

How can I make it work on root too?

To sum-up, I need 301 redirects, otherwise there will be duplicates of content!!

`http://www.domain.com/` R--> `http://domain.com/`

`http://domain.com/` R--> `http://domain.com`

`http://domain.com/sub/` R--> `http://domain.com/sub`

`http://domain.com/sub/index.php` R--> `http://domain.com/sub`

`http://domain.com/sub/index.php#anchor` R--> `http://domain.com/sub#anchor`

`http://domain.com/sub/#anchor` R--> `http://domain.com/sub#anchor`

Comment: `http://domain.com/ R--> http://domain.com` should already be happening as browser takes care of that.

Comment: Another point, anchors cannot be handled server side as server won't even get `#anchor` in the HTTP request i.e. only `http://domain.com/sub/` will be received in Apache logs.

Comment: how about removing `/index.php` ?

Comment: @anubhava browsers don't remove the trailing slash, they just hide it.

Comment: Yes, hiding is same as removing from client's view. What I meant is that web server gets `/` as the requested URI in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules to meet all the requirements including removal of `index.php`. Do remember that anchors cannot be preserved on server side  as server won't even get `#anchor` in the HTTP request i.e. only `http://domain.com/sub/` will be received in Apache logs.

```
# Options
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DirectorySlash off

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1##%{HTTPS}s ^(.+)##(?:on(s)|)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/*(/.*)?/index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# remove trailing slash from all URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# internally add trailing / to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

<FilesMatch ^\.>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files *.inc>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't trim trailing slashes, you're fighting the normal directory structure of URLs. There is no such URL as `http://domain.com` even if your browser hides it, the slash is still being sent in the request and will be added back to a URL copied from an address bar.

Doing a redirect for a single domain is good. Automatic 301 redirects (the kind that Apache does) from `http://domain.com/foo` to `http://domain.com/foo/` are good for SEO. How are `index.php` strings in your URLs in the first place? There's no need for them to be there; make sure all your own links are free of them. The easiest way to ensure only unique pages are indexed is with `<link rel=canonical href="…">`.

Comment: So you suggest not to remove the trailing slash and 301 redirect non slashed links to slashed links?

Comment: Yes, that's what Apache already wants to do, though check the network tab of your dev tools window to ensure they are 301s, not 302s. Don't worry about other site's links to yours with `index.php` in; they will fade over time. As long as *you* avoid using them and use canonicals, you will have nice search engine results and actually lessen the chance of requirimg a redirect which is better for performance.

Comment: You can even change Apache's configuration for `DirectorySlash` to avoid any redirect performance hit, but beware of the security note in the docs.